# UIStackview weird behaviour with size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to recreate the iOS stock calculator app using UIStackView in iOS 9.2 with Xcode 7.2.
I succesfully created the portrait version, now I was working with Size Classes to implement the landscape one.

The approach I used to create the layout it was to have:

- a **UILabel for the display**, which has leading,trailing and top constraints from the superview
- a **UIStackview as container** just below, which has leading, trailing and bottom constraints from the superview and the top from the UILabel. This Stackview *stacks* its components vertically with **"distribution":"fill equally"** and **"alignment":"fill"**
- inside this UIStackview, **one UIStackview for each row of buttons**. These stackviews *stack* their components horizontally with **"distribution":"fill equally"**, **"alignment":"fill"** and **"spacing":"1"** (to recreate 1pt black border)

As you can see from the screenshot here ([Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN83F.png)), the result I got on the storyboard it's perfect: all seem to working fine and Xcode don't give any error neither warning!

However, when I compile, the result on the simulator ([Simulator and Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onnAL.png)) it's completely different.
The buttons, in particular the ones present only in landscape, seem to go outside the stackview for some reason (see the screenshot above for the View Debug).
Anyone have experienced this problem? It's really really weird because I think the logic behind the layout it's ok.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? I'm in a similar situation. I tried playing around with compression and hugging priority but still my views end up outside the stack in landscape

Comment: Unfortunately no! I have to admit that it's been a while since the last time I worked with iOS, so I don't know if this problem has been fixed!

Comment: How did you, using stack views, get the 0 to be larger than the others? Whenever I try that (fill proportional with constraints) it tends to warp once it's embedded in a second stack and the resolution changes.